# How to achieve backward compatibility with a changed java class structure

Tags: java, design-patterns

We have a class structure like below and

```
public class Partner {
   Long id;
   String name;
   PartnerDetails details;
}

public class PartnerDetails {
   String address;
   Long share;
   PartnerGroup group;
}

public class PartnerGroup {
   Long id;
   String groupName;
}
```

We are using `partner.getDetails().getGroup().getGroupName();` to fetch *group name* of a partner currently.

But due to further enhancements, now we are moving ***PartnerGroup group*** property to ***Partner*** class and we are not deleting ***PartnerDetails.group*** property to avoid issues with the old records. Now the structure will be like below:

```
public class Partner {
   Long id;
   String name;
   PartnerDetails details;
   PartnerGroup group;
}

public class PartnerDetails {
   String address;
   Long share;
   PartnerGroup group;
}

public class PartnerGroup {
   Long id;
   String groupName;
}
```

For new records we are going to use `partner.getGroup().getGroupName();`

Please advise what is the best approach to work with new structure for new records and old structure for older records to fetch groupname.

Answer (score 3):

1. Replace all usages of `partner.getDetails().getGroup().getGroupName();` with `partner.getPartnerGroupName()`
2. Create method `Partner#getPartnerGroupName` that handles implementation details internally:

```
public class Partner {
   Long id;
   String name;
   PartnerDetails details;
   PartnerGroup group;
   
   public String getPartnerGroupName() {
       if (group != null) {
           return group.getGroupName();
       }
       return getDetails().getGroup().getGroupName(); 
   }
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter